# Chocolatier sampler boxes problem: applying goal programming and mixed-integer programing to optimally compromise goals.

Tags: statistics, linear-programming, integer-programming

QUESTION:

> A boutique chocolatier is planning to make a number of sampler boxes,
>   each containing $36$ chocolates.  (Therefore the total number of
>   chocolates should be divisible by $36$.)  The chocolatier would like
>   to achieve the following goals:
>
> - include at least $300$ Hazelnut Glories
> - include at least as many Vanilla Surrenders as Hazelnut Glories,
> - include at least $240$ Caramel Desires,
> - include at least $400$ Dark Mysteries,
> - produce no more than $27$ sampler boxes of chocolates overall.
>
> Assume the goals are equally important.
>
> (a) Apply goal programming methods to formulate a mixed-integer
>   program to find the optimal compromise between these goals.
>
> (b) Solve your mixed-integer program in *Excel* and interpret the
>   solution.  Your answer in your main report should include the IP
>   formulation, the optimal solution, and an interpretation of the
>   optimal solution for the boutique chocolatier.  You should also submit
>   the *Excel* file you used to solve the IP.

Can someone help me figuring out how to calculate this question?

In this question, I have 4 variables (I think it would be more easily to calculate), and 5 goals.

SO for the 27 boxes, I multiply the number of 36 = 972.

Then, it subject to 5 constraints, and 4 variables are integers and all decision values is large than or equal to 0.

Then when I enter the question into Excel Solver, I got two different answers and both are quite reasonable.

The first answer is equal to: 300, 32, 240, 400.

And for the second answer is equal to: 32, 300, 240, 400.

The only different is that for the first answer, I have click the box of all variables are non-negative.

SO, I don't know which answer is the best or actually i do it wrong??
Thanks for your help!!!

Comment: Please type in the question instead of posting an image.  Text is searchable whereas an image is not.  An image also takes longer to download than text.

Answer (score 1):

I don´t know which program you have. And I cannot interpret your solutions.

I would transform the inequalities into equalities by using slack variables ($y_i$).

$h+v+c+d+y_1=972$ (Whitout the slack variable, this is also a inequality.)

If the sum of the number of chocolates is divisible by 36, then $y_1$ has to be divisible by 36:

$\frac{y_1}{36}=z_1$

$h-y_2=300$

$v-y_3=h$

$c-y_4=400$

$d-y_5=500$

The objective function is the sum of $y_i$:

$\texttt{min} \ \ y_1+y_2+y_3+y_4+y_5 $

The values of the variables have to be natural numbers:

$h,v,c,d,z_1\in \mathbb N_0$ and $y_1,y_2,y_3,y_4,y_5 \geq 0$